# IS_IOSTAT_END error in Mac OSX (Fortran)

Tags: macos, error-handling, fortran, iostat

I am writing a code in Fortran to read a list of properties from a file, and am using the IOSTAT function to skip invalid data. The relevant section of code is as follows:

```
do j=1,1000
read(22,*,IOSTAT=ios) step,T,K,U,Tot,P
If(IS_IOSTAT_END(ios)) Exit !exits loop if value is not number or end of file
IF(ios.ne.0) cycle

sumT=sumT+T
sumU=sumU+U
sumK = sumK + K
sumKsq = sumKsq + (K**2.d0)

end if
end do
```

This code has previously worked fine when running on Linux, but when running on Mac OSX I get the error message 'IS_IOSTAT_END has no implicit type'. Could somebody please explain how to correct this?

Thanks

Comment: `IS_IOSTAT_END` is fortran 2003. In case your compiler doesn't have it `ios.eq.-1` should work.

Comment: What compiler, including version, are you using?  Another option is to  update the compiler.

Comment: Thank you both, I updated the compiler (gfortran) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The intrinsic procedure `IS_IOSTAT_END(i)` is defined since Fortran 2003. Sufficiently recent compiler version must be used.